# how to compare two files in linux skipping some specific part

Tags: linux

I know that there are lot of utilities to compare files in linux like `diff`, `cksum`.

But i want to compare two files with some condition. i want to skip a word or the the word starting with some "xyz" in two files and compare. Is that posible possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Please give two example files and point out what shall be compared and what the output shall look like.

Answer (score 0):

Compare tools are usually "per line" oriented, not word oriented.

For a similar situation I needed to compare log files where some unique identifiers were normal to differ but they were very frequent in the files so the diff tools were not giving clean outputs.

My solution was to take the second file and make a temporary copy where I replaced the unique values with the same value as the first file and then compare.

If there was more than one unique value, I then made a copy for each file where I replaced all the "`xyz*`" strings with a neutral string identical on both files and then compare.